# Editing an existing Lightning app in the developer console

Tags: lightning-apps

I've created a new lightning app in a Winter 15 developer edition org.

I can access it using a URL such as:
    https://.lightning.force.com//.app

Now I've closed the developer console I want to go back and edit the lightning app some more.

**How do I open an existing lightning app in the developer console?**

I can't see an option to open an existing lightning app under the open menu item.

Nor can I see an option to open a lightning component directly from the developer console. I did have success from `Build > Develop > Lightning Components BETA` using the edit link to get into the developer console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the new command function Ctrl-Shift-A (File > Open Lightning Resources) to access those files in the Developer Console.

Comment: Ah, that might be why I can't find it. It freezes the developer console when opened on my tablet. I'll try it again later with a full computer.

Comment: I've been playing with it today, and it works for me, so I'd assume it's just not tablet friendly.

Comment: Confirmed, it works on a standard PC, but not on my tablet browser.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe much, if any, testing has been done for doing dev on tablets. That being said, if you could indicate which tablet, OS version, browser, etc. that you've had issues with, it is something we would like to track.

Thanks,

Skip

Comment: I can appreciate why tablet browsers aren't high on the testing priority for the development tools. I was using a Surface 2 tablet running Windows 8.1 during Dreamforce to take notes and do some quick tests for new functionality. The "desktop" browser available was IE 11.0.9600.17351. Using the Open Lightning Resources options caused the browser to hang.

Comment: I just checked for bugs opened on this and the tools PM opened one. He didn't specify if it was tablet or not, but it was definitely IE-related.

Answer (score 0):

go to app manager,select the app you want to edit, click on the drop down  at end of the last column in the app..
[image: the following image illustrates the app edit selection]

Comment: Does that actually open the Developer Console?